# RelativeLayout inside a parent LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Here is the structure of the layout of my application:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TabHost>
        <LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TabWidget />
                <FrameLayout />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

The above layout works perfectly. I want to add a textview to show a text in the bottom of the screen. So for showing the text always in the bottom of the screen, I need to create a relative layout.

I have created a RelativeLayout and placed the textview inside the RelativeLayout like this :

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I add this to the original view. I have tried several ways to add but nothing works! :(

**My aim is to a show a text in the bottom of the screen. Is there any way to do this using any layout.**

Comment: You can't answer your question from the information you give, maybe add screenshots of what the layout looks like and will look like?

Comment: @Blundell I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: there are a few ways to do so: use RelativeLayout and make a text view to be aligned to the bottom; use vertical LinearLayout and define weight in such way that TextView occupies as much space as it needs at the bottom and the rest is taken by other views. I am not sure I understand your problem completely to be more specific

Comment: Here's doing it with a ListView, You could obviously just change out the Listview for your complex layout above: http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/listview-with-a-footer-item-t49281.html

Comment: Thank you! Asahi and Blundell  I will take a look at this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from : [ListView with Footer Item](http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/listview-with-a-footer-item-t49281.html) and adapted

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                <!--Put whatever view item you want here -->
                <TextView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_view"
       >
        <TabHost>
            <LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout>
                    <TabWidget />
                    <FrameLayout />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

But I'm sure there's a nicer way to do it with the amount of nested layouts you have.

Answer (score 2):

Add the RelativeLayout beneath the TabHost, make the parent LinearLayout also relative and make the child one android:layout_alignInParentBottom="true"